# How to properly declare a return type of a future subclass type of a related generic base class?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming, parametric-namespaces

Someone is trying to achieve an abstraction in ASP.NET MVC with C#.

They have a base entity controller which should do most of the job for its derived classes(entities). In it, they have a problematic method which should return the database context of each table(they are not using any DB frameworks like EF). Here is the method:

```
protected abstract DbContext<EntityViewModel> CreateContext();
```

So, say they have a Category table, the method should be implemented:

```
protected override DbContext<EntityViewModel> CreateContext()
{
    return new CategoryDbContext();
}
```

But C# says they can't implicitly cast it, etc...

Here are the context classes:

```
public abstract class DbContext<T>
{
    public abstract void Create(T entity);

    public abstract List<T> Read(ModifyData data);

    public abstract void Update(T entity);

    public abstract void Delete(T entity);
}

public class CategoryDbContext : DbContext<CategoryViewModel>
{
    public override void Create(CategoryViewModel entity)
    {
    }

    public override List<CategoryViewModel> Read(ModifyData data)
    {
    }

    public override void Update(CategoryViewModel entity)
    {
    }

    public override void Delete(CategoryViewModel entity)
    {
    }
}
```

What is wrong here in this design and how can these classes be changed to work?

Comment: If the question was marked as a duplicate, why repost? What was the other question?

Comment: I don't have the link anymore to the duplicate that it was marked with, but it was the one of the "fruit bowl" generics casting question variations.

Comment: @AlexFoxGill for those who can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605068/generic-abstraction-in-c-sharp I voted for *undelete*

Comment: The answer to the other question essentially answered why the original poster could not cast CategoryDbContext into DbContext<EntityViewModel>.  It did not answer the following statement and question from the original post: "I am trying to achieve an abstraction in ASP.NET MVC with C#... ...What am I doing wrong here?"

Comment: I am curious as to why this question is getting down voted.

Comment: @TyreeJackson Remove the meta content, i.e. "(written w/o perm)", "the question was marked as dup", etc. For the person reading the question, it doesn't matter if it was based in another question, as long as it is useful. The others downvoted because they didn't understand why you did it. So write the question as if it was yours, at the end you can just provide a link to the user who thought of it.

Comment: @Armfoot I've updated the question as per your feedback.  Thanks again!  Your responses here and on SO Meta have been very helpful for an SO contributor newbie such as me.

Comment: @TyreeJackson nicely done, the important thing to notice is that your question is valuable, specially if it relates to a recurring problem and was not properly addressed by the existing questions. Glad you were persistent enough to make sure other people will know how to solve it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the base entity controller class to something like the following:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityController<TDbContext, TEntityViewModel>
    where TDbContext : DbContext<TEntityViewModel>
    where TEntityViewModel : EntityViewModel
{
    protected abstract TDbContext CreateContext();
}
```

And then subclass the BaseEntityController like so:

```
public class CategoryController : BaseEntityController<CategoryDbContext, CategoryViewModel>
{
    protected abstract TDbContext CreateContext();
}
```

And then subclass the DbContext as so:

```
public class CategoryDbContext : DbContext<CategoryViewModel>
{
    public override void Create(CategoryViewModel entity)
    {
    }

    public override List<CategoryViewModel> Read(ModifyData data)
    {
    }

    public override void Update(CategoryViewModel entity)
    {
    }

    public override void Delete(CategoryViewModel entity)
    {
    }
}
```

By adding a generic type parameter for the subclass form of the DbContext itself to the BaseEntityController class, we are able to return that placeholder instead of the base generic form of the DbContext thereby avoiding casting issues and making the code more strongly typed.

As a **bonus**, we can then refactor the above code to DRY up the generic type parameter declarations itself using a bit of generic nested class [(parametric/generic namespace) technique](http://tyreejackson.com/generics-net-part5-generic-namespaces/).  For example:

```
public abstract class Entity<TEntity, TDbContext, TViewModel>
    where TEntity : Entity<TEntity, TDbContext, TEntityViewModel>
    where TDbContext : Entity<TEntity, TDbContext, TEntityViewModel>.BaseDbContext, new()
    where TViewModel : Entity<TEntity, TDbContext, TEntityViewModel>.BaseViewModel
{
    public class EntityController
    {
        protected TDbContext CreateContext() { return new TDbContext(); }
    }

    public abstract class BaseDbContext
    {
        public abstract void Create(TViewModel entity);
        public abstract List<TViewModel> Read(ModifyData data);
        public abstract void Update(TViewModel entity);
        public abstract void Delete(TViewModel entity);
    }

    public abstract class BaseViewModel {}

}
```

Then subclass(sub-namespace?) the the generic namespace and its members as so:

```
public class Category : Entity<Category, Category.DbContext, Category.ViewModel>
{
    pubic class DbContext : BaseDbContext
    {
        public override void Create(CategoryViewModel entity)
        {
        }

        public override List<ViewModel> Read(ModifyData data)
        {
        }

        public override void Update(CategoryViewModel entity)
        {
        }

        public override void Delete(CategoryViewModel entity)
        {
        }
    }

    pubic class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Note that without further requirements indicating otherwise, we have been able to eliminate the need to subclass the EntityController at this point.  But should we need to subclass it, we can change EntityController into BaseEntityController, and optionally add a generic type parameter for its subclass form to the Entity "generic namespace" in case we need to use or return that future subclass type within the base code.

Comment: it's preparing for a copy-paste :)

Comment: @Jashaszun it's an old tab stop formatting technique commonly used in the old days of writing sql statements.  It's intended to be used with collapsed methods in tools like Visual Studio or other similar editors that support code folding.  Google elastic tabstops.

Comment: @TyreeJackson Alright. Although that makes sense, I think it would be better to have code formatted normally (i.e. one space between keywords, etc.).

Comment: @DavidL Thanks for your sacrifice.

Comment: @DavidL You then must learn to work smarter, not harder (unless you are paid by the hour) :-) Notepad++, search and replace using regular expressions, `([A-Za-z>])  +` (two spaces before the `+`) to `\1 ` (one space after the `1`)